# Change color of text for input field using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have created an input field for a log-in feature on the page however I have been trying to change the color of the text in the field using css. Is this possible. I have tried many routes however none seem to work so far. Below is the code for the email portion of the sign in.

```
 <input class="form-control ng-class:{'error':dashboard.showFormErrors && !dashboard.signinForm.email.$valid}"
               data-ng-model="signinController.signin.email"
               type="email"
               name="email"
               id="email"
               placeholder="Email"
               ng-minlength="2"
               ng-maxlength="3"
               required>
```

Comment: It would be great if you could accept an answer, if any, that solve your question, or let us know what is missing, so we can find one that does

Comment: I posted the answer/solution that I used on the bottom of the page.

Comment: An answer already had `focus` as a suggestion, accept that instead of post an answer of your own using the very same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

The CSS can target the input of type "email" or just this unique input.

Email input element:

```
input[type=email]{
    color: red;
}
```

Or specific id="email":

```
#email {
    color: red;
}
```

Here's a snippet:

```css
input[type=email] {
  color: red;
}
#email2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control ng-class:{'error':dashboard.showFormErrors && !dashboard.signinForm.email.$valid}" 
       data-ng-model="signinController.signin.email" 
       type="email" 
       name="email" 
       id="email" 
       placeholder="Email" 
       ng-minlength="2" 
       ng-maxlength="3" 
       required>
<input class="form-control ng-class:{'error':dashboard.showFormErrors && !dashboard.signinForm.email.$valid}" 
       data-ng-model="signinController.signin.email" 
       type="email" 
       name="email" 
       id="email2" 
       placeholder="Email"
       ng-minlength="2"
       ng-maxlength="3" 
       required>
```

If this still isn't working, you may have to use the "!important" attribute to override other CSS setters.

```
color: red !important;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this in your css file :

```
#email{
  color:red;
}
```

You can give color of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Create a css class that holds the changes you want to do to the fields , and then affect the class to the input tags via ng-class directive.
In your code the syntax is wrong I think.. but that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the following code
    input { color: red; }

Answer (score 1):

Many of your suggestions work great. This is the route I used with css

```
input, select, textarea{
    color: #076000;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
    color: #076000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible that you can change your input's text color with **CSS** and there are quite some ways to that depending upon the result you want to achieve.

For example, if you want to set your colour to `blue` and have it always stay blue, you can use the following code:

```
#email {
    color: blue; /* Or color: #0000ff */
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to change your text's colour when your selected input has focus, you can use this instead:

```
#email:focus {
    color: blue; /* Or color: #0000ff */
}
```

You can also change your colour on hover, but this is not something that is used very often:

```
#email:hover {
    color: blue; /* Or color: #0000ff */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change input color for different types of input use respective tag (with/without its pseudo state)

```
input, select, textarea {
    color: #000;
}
input:focus, input:active

/* etc... */

input[type=text] - will only select text fields
input[type=password] - will only select password fields
input[type=number] - will only select number fields
/* etc.. */

input[type=text]:focus
/* etc */
```

For placeholder styling

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```